# 4 equation with 2 variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 4 equation with two variables, want to solve it in Matlab, can anyone help me. The two variables of the equation I want to find out is `\theta` and `\phi`.

```
$\cos2\theta+sin2\theta+1=1$

$cos^2\phi cos^2\theta+cos^2\phi cos2\theta sin2\theta+cos^2\phi cos2\theta+sin2\phi cos2\phi cos2\theta sin2\theta+sin2\phi cos2\phi sin^2\theta+sin2\phi cos2\phi sin2\theta+0.4837=0$

$cos2\phi cos^2\theta sin2\phi + cos2\theta sin^2\phi sin2\theta +cos2\phi cos2\theta sin2\phi sin2\theta+cos2\phi cos2\theta sin2\phi +sin^2\phi sin2\theta=1$

$cos^2\theta sin2\phi -cos2\phi sin^2\theta-cos2\phi sin2\theta +cos2\theta sin2\phi - cos2\phi cos2\theta sin2\theta +cos2\theta sin2\phi sin2\theta=0 $
```

Comment: Did you try using the symbolic toolbox? Take a look at the examples here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/solve.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've translated your functions correctly, the problem appears to have no solutions. Try this for any starting value:

```
function myFcn    

    X = fsolve(@F, 2*pi*rand(2,1))

end

function val = F(X)

    th = X(1);
    ph = X(2);

    val =  [
        cos(2*th) + sin(2*th)
        cos(ph).^2.*cos(th).^2 + cos(ph).^2.*cos(2*th).*sin(2*th) + cos(ph).^2.*cos(2*th) + sin(2*ph).*cos(2*ph).*cos(2*th).*sin(2*th) + sin(2*ph).*cos(2*ph).*sin(th).^2 + sin(2*ph).*cos(2*ph).*sin(2*th) + 0.4837
        cos(2*ph).*cos(th).^2.*sin(2*ph) + cos(2*th).*sin(ph).^2.*sin(2*th) + cos(2*ph).*cos(2*th).*sin(2*ph).*sin(2*th) + cos(2*ph).*cos(2*th).*sin(2*ph) + sin(ph).^2.*sin(2*th) - 1
        cos(th).^2.*sin(2*ph) - cos(2*ph).*sin(th).^2 - cos(2*ph).*sin(2*th) + cos(2*th).*sin(2*ph) - cos(2*ph).*cos(2*th).*sin(2*th) + cos(2*th).*sin(2*ph).*sin(2*th)
    ];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an [overdetermined equations system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system) and you should solve them with [WLSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) model.
overdetermined equations systems have equations more than unknowns.
WLSE model solve these systems with an algorithm that can help you to write your equation to solve the problem. after that you can write them in MATLAB easily

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._